# pasar dos valores del vue a href

Tags: php, html, vue.js

Tengo esta routa efectivamente ya se encuentra funcionando y me agarra los valores que deberia tener

```
<td v-if= "permisoCrear">
                    <a v-bind:href="'/formCargarHoras/'+proyecto.id_proyecto+'/'+idUsuario" target="_self">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-edit" v-if= "proyecto.permisoCrear"></i>
                  </td>
```

El router lo tengo de esta manera el cual los valores del idProyecto y IdUsuario deberia ser los correspondiente a los que se encuentran arriba

```
Route::get('/formCargarHoras/{idProyecto}/{idUsuario}', 'ProyectoController@formCargarHoras')->where('idProyecto', '[0-9]+');
```

Pero cuando los paso por aqui al parecer pierdo el valor de idUsuario asi se deberia anotar si voy arrastando los dos valores_

```
function formCargarHoras($idProyecto,$idUsuario, Request $request){

      $request->session()->put('idProyecto',$idProyecto,'idUsuario', $idUsuario);
      return view('horasCargables/CargarHoras');

    }
```

Comment: Cómo es eso de que pierdes el valor de $idUsuario?

Comment: Cuando trato de sacarlo en la siguiente pagina dice que es 0

Comment: Cómo tratas de sacarlo? Y qué te muestra si haces un `dd($idUsuario);` en la primer línea del método en controlador?

Comment: No se que sucede ahora si aparece, esta cosa me va volver loco . Funciona cuando quiere. No modifique nada. Bueno igual gracias

Comment: Posiblemente a lo que te refieres es a que no lo puedes obtener de la sesión. Por eso preguntaba

Comment: si no lo podía obtener de la sesión pero lo raro es que obtenía uno de los dos pero nunca los dos

Comment: En resumen a mi respuesta lo que te falto es  agregar corchetes a esta funcion   *** $request->session()->put(['idProyecto',$idProyecto,'idUsuario', $idUsuario]);***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LA primera parte la estas resolviendo con vue esta bien te debe de hacer una ruta de esta forma.

```
/formCargarHoras/{id_proyecto}/{idUsuario}
```

En tu ruta yo no la validaría un una expresión regular si no dejaría que el modelo se encargara de validar la que lo que esta mandando el cliente esta correcto o existe en la base de datos.

```
Route::get('/formCargarHoras/{idProyecto}/{idUsuario}','ProyectoController@formCargarHoras');
```

La ruta simplemente quedaría así.

En el controlador es donde viene lo bueno.

```
  // saltandome hasta el metodo.

  public function formCargarHoras(
         ProyectoModel $idProyecto, 
         Usermodel $idUsuario, 
         Request $request
         ){

            \Session::put('idProyecto',$idProyecto);
            \Session::put('idUsuario', $idUsuario);
            return view('horasCargables/CargarHoras');

    }
```

> Debes de configurar los modelos para que el parámetro de la ruta sea el campo de con el que buscara en la tabla de la base de datos.

Es sencillo solo debes de agregar esta función en el modelo de cada uno.

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    // es el nombre del campo en la tabla por el cual se ara la busqueda
    return 'nombre_campo';
}
```

Ahora la explicacion.

Al dejar que implícitamente eloquent busque la concordancia con el parámetro deseado lo que ara es regresara **la colección de la primera concordancia**. Si no existe te mandara un **error 404**. Con esto aseguras la existencia del parametro en la base de datos.

Segunda.

Los request extienden del facade **Session** para manejar las variables de sesión.

En la función **put**  que recuerde en la documentación no viene que le puedas pasar múltiples variables. Lo que viene es que le puedes pasar un array de objetos. Es por eso que no te esta guardando los valores. Cito a continuación la documentación oficial del método put en el facade Session.

```
// Para almacenar datos en la sesión, normalmente usará el putmétodo o el session helpe:

// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```